# Undirected graph with even degree of vertices and finding directios s.t. indegree=outdegree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So we have an undirected graph $G(V, E)$, such that each vertex has an even degree. Is it possible to "impose" direction on the graph in a way, that an indegree and an outdegree of each vertex iarr equal?

I was thinking about the induction of edges but not sure how to approach that problem? But since in the problem it is nothing said about connectedness I´m having real problems with the solution

Comment: Do you know of an equivalent condition for a graph having all vertices of even degree? It should be a very early theorem in any graph theory textbook.

Comment: You mean that the graph is Eulerian?

Comment: Exactly; now, given an Eulerian circuit, say $C$, there is an easy way to orient the edges of $G$ to satisfy your requirement. Can you see how?

Comment: Doesn't Eulerian circuit require connectedness?

Comment: Very true; I'm glad you're being careful. However, considering any component of $G$, say $H$, as its own graph, we can say that $H$ (viewing it as a graph) is Eulerian. Hence each nontrivial component of $G$ has a circuit which exhausts every edge.

Comment: So to say, we if $G$ is not connected then we divide it into separate into connected subgraphs? And therefore each subgraph has a circuit?

Comment: Sure, you can think of it that way. For instance, consider the graph $G$ = $K_5 \cup K_{2, 4}$. $G$ is not Eulerian, since it has more than one nontrivial component (disconnected graphs can be Eulerian so long as they only have one nontrivial component). However, each connected component of $G$ is Eulerian, and we can get Eulerian circuits $C_1$ and $C_2$ of $K_5$ and $K_{2, 4}$ respectively. We may then use these 2 circuits to construct an orientation where every vertex has equal in- and out-degree.

Comment: Thank you very much! And could you help me with the construction of an orientation. Somehow initiativly it does make sense but I don't know how to write it mathematicaly

Comment: Try finding an Eulerian circuit $C$ of $K_5$ (for example). View the circuit as beginning and ending at some vertex $v$. Trace along the cycle choosing an orientation for each edge, and see what works to get the in- and out-degree of every vertex equalling 2.

Comment: I will try! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time so I have tried with $K_5$ all possible options I think and if I follow Eulerian circuit. So I get it in a way firstly  we orient outer as Eulerian circuit and then orient inner edges accordingly or? And for $K_6$ we can't do it?

Comment: It sounds like you got the idea for $K_5$, basically just partition it into 2 copies of $C_5$ and orient the edges "along" the 2 cycles. In general, I've given the argument as an answer (see below). Of course, $K_6$ is 5-regular, so it is not Eulerian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as how I've essentially spelled out a whole solution in the comments, I may as well post it in full here:

Let $G$ be a graph with all vertices of even degree, and let $H$ be a connected (nontrivial) component of $G$. Since $H$ is connected with all vertices of even degree, $H$ is Eulerian, say with Eulerian circuit $C$. View $C$ as beginning and ending at some vertex $v$. Following along $C$, orient each edge "forward" as we traverse through all the edges of $C$. In an Eulerian circuit, every time we "enter" a vertex, we must "exit" the vertex with the next edge (save for the first and last vertices, $v$). Hence every time we contribute an edge to the in-degree of a given vertex, the very next edge along $C$ will contribute once to the out-degree of this vertex (using the orientation we agreed to above; again, this holds for every vertex except $v$).

Iterating this process for each $H$, we obtain an orientation of $G$ in which every vertex has equal in- and out-degree, as desired.